# How to show/set row names to matrixInput (shinyIncubator)

Tags: css, r, matrix, shiny

I'm able to create a matrix using `matrixInput` function:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c("0","0"), 1, 2))
colnames(df) <- c("Input1", "Input2")
rownames(df) <- c("rown1")
matrixInput(inputId = 'data', label = 'Add/Remove Rows', data = df)
```

Working OK --> I'm able to Unhide/print the COLUMN names using the below code .............................           **NOT OK** --> UNABLE TO **UNHIDE** the **ROW NAME**(s)

```
tags$head(
 tags$style(type = "text/css"
                   , "table.data { width: 300px; }"
                   , ".well {width: 80%; background-color: NULL; border: 0px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255) inset;}"
                   , ".tableinput .hide {display: table-header-group; color: black; align-items: center; text-align: center; align-self: center;}"
                   , ".tableinput-container {width: 100%; text-align: center;}"
                   , ".tableinput-buttons {margin: 10px;}"
                   , ".data {background-color: rgb(255,255,255);}"
                   , ".table th, .table td {text-align: center;}"
       )
      )
```

how might this might be possible?

Comment: `matrixInput` currently discards the `rownames` data so it is not available to hide/unhide in the resulting html.

Comment: thank you what would you recommend to use instead? I need to have an input matrix with visible row and column names. Or any work-around with other options?