# Customizing the matrixInput function from shinyincubator to remove +/- and show column names

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-incubator/blob/master/R/tableinput.R

Here is the link to the link to the code for the `matrixInput` function
of the `shinyIncubator` package.
I have two problems, that relate to the css/html part of the code; which is a language I have no clue off. 
Here is a  simple reproducible example:

server.R

`shinyServer(function(input, output) {})`

ui.R

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyIncubator")
df <- data.frame(matrix(c("0","0"), 1, 2))
colnames(df) <- c("first", "second")

shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Matrix input problem"),
    sidebarPanel(
      matrixInput(inputId = 'data', label = '', data = df)

    )
    ,
    mainPanel()
  )
)
```

I would like to change two things in the customized matrixInput function :

-Make the +/- option on the rows disappear (no possibility to add rows)

-Show the columns names of the matrix that was used as input (I saw related subjects but the  solutions provided don't seem to work for me)

Can anyone with experience in said languages help out?

Answer (score 0):

Hello readers of the question.

Since my need for an answer was pretty urgent, I took some time to just randomly try out things myself, laso trying to get inspired from related subjects.
I think I have a function the does the things I wanted corretly now. 
I will post the code here.

Basically it is the same as the original, but there are just some things I disabled by putting them as comments as you will see.

```
matrixInput2 <- function(inputId, label, data) {
  addResourcePath(
    prefix='tableinput', 
    directoryPath=system.file('tableinput', 
                              package='shinyIncubator'))

  tagList(
    singleton(
      tags$head(
        tags$link(rel = 'stylesheet',
                  type = 'text/css',
                  href = 'tableinput/tableinput.css'),
        tags$script(src = 'tableinput/tableinput.js')
      )
    ),

    tags$div(
      class = 'control-group tableinput-container',
      tags$label(
        class = "control-label",
        label
        #THIS seems to be responsible (atleast partially, regarding the display) for the +/- buttons
        # ,
        # tags$div(
        #   class = 'tableinput-buttons',
        #   tags$button(
        #     type = 'button', class = 'btn btn-mini tableinput-settings hide',
        #     tags$i(class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon-cog')
        #   ),
        #   HTML('<a href="#" class="tableinput-plusrow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign icon-plus-sign"></i></a>'),
        #   HTML('<a href="#" class="tableinput-minusrow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign icon-minus-sign"></i></a>')
        # )
      ),
      tags$table(
        id = inputId,
        class = 'tableinput data table table-bordered table-condensed',
        tags$colgroup(
          lapply(names(data), function(name) {
            tags$col('data-name' = name,
                     'data-field' = name,
                     'data-type' = 'numeric')
          })
        )
        ,
        tags$thead(
          #Here I just put this line as a comment. Setting the class as 'hide' hid the column names. I don't know where the deal with the rownames is.
          # class = 'hide',
          tags$tr(
            lapply(names(data), function(name) {
              tags$th(name)
            })
          )
        ),
        tags$tbody(
          lapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {
            tags$tr(
              lapply(names(data), function(name) {
                tags$td(
                  div(tabindex=0, as.character(data[i,name]))
                )
              })
            )
          })
        )
      ),
      tags$div(
        class = 'tableinput-editor modal hide fade',
        tags$div(
          class = 'modal-header',
          HTML('<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'),
          tags$h3(label)
        ),
        tags$div(
          class = 'modal-body',

          HTML('
               <form class="form-horizontal">
               <div class="control-group">
               <label class="control-label">Rows</label>
               <div class="controls">
               <input type="number" class="tableinput-rowcount">
               </div>
               </div>
               <div class="control-group">
               <label class="control-label">Columns</label>
               <div class="controls">
               <input type="number" class="tableinput-colcount">
               </div>
               </div>
               </form>'
          )
          ),
        tags$div(
          class = 'modal-footer',
          tags$a(href = '#', class = 'btn btn-primary tableinput-edit', 'OK'),
          tags$a(href = '#',
                 class = 'btn',
                 'data-dismiss' = 'modal',
                 'aria-hidden' = 'true',
                 'Cancel')
        )
          )
      )
    )
}
```

I hope this will help some people that want to do the same thing as me.
If anyone with more experience here can do something about the rownames; it would probably be interesting. (I read in a related subject that it's a bit harder to do than for the column names as matrixInput seems to be discarding them instead of just hiding)

source: [How to show/set row names to matrixInput (shinyIncubator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197593/how-to-show-set-row-names-to-matrixinput-shinyincubator)

The repoducible example from the question can be used to try it out.

Cheers

Comment: If anyone gets a bug with this modified function, post it here and we'll try to solve it